# manipulating and searching within large files in python

Tags: python, search, file

I apologize if this question has been answered already, but I cannot seem to find a page that describes this process. What I am trying to do is to take a large file (The new york times corpus), change it to a list of words using the split function, and then search through that long list for certain words. I have been able to get python to print the file with this code

```
words=open('nyt.txt')
for line in words:
    print (line)
```

but I would like to be able to use words.split() on this function afterward.

So far, I have been developing the program using a small corpus that I just type in like this

```
words= ('A B. C D E F G A. B C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F G')
```

but, rather than copying and pasting the nyt into the parentheses (this doesn't work, the file is too large). I would rather have it source the file into the variable name.

Once again, I am sorry if this has been asked and answered before, as is likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is called a *generator*. In your case, it could look like this:

```
def words(lines):
    for line in lines:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word
```

This processes the file line by line, so it doesn't have to read the entire file into memory at once. The `yield` keyword turns the function result into a generator. Usage:

```
import sys
for word in words(sys.stdin):
    print word
```

---

Edit: If I understand you correctly this time round, you just want to read all words into a list? Easy enough:

```
lines = open('nyt.txt')
words = []
for line in lines:
    words.extend(line.split())
print words
```

Comment: I am not completely certain if it is important for it to be read in line by line. What I am looking for is for it to end up having the code set up so that one could type in print (words), and it would print the file in question.

Comment: I hate to be bothersome, but this does not seem to be functioning. That is all that I want to do-read all of the words in a file into a named list that can then be called, but when using that code, the line doesn't seem to want to terminate- if I hit enter it never gets back to >>>. Is it possible that this is a result of working in python 3 instead of 2.7? If it is, I could probably just download 2.7 and make some small changes to make the rest of the code compatible.

Comment: I was mistaken-it is doing that because it is processing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `nltk`. It's a huge project and it has tools for working with corpora. The project is written in Python and available at http://www.nltk.org/.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that. I am sure that I am overdue to learn about something so connected to what I am doing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but in case you want to get individual words, you need to split each line by using space and punctuation marks, and then add result to some variable: `allwords.append(line.split(' '))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but are you looking for something like this?

```
words = open('README')
word_list = []
for l in words:
     word_list.append(l)
```

If you're going to be doing anything more sophisticated with words, you should look at the [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) package.

Comment: I will certainly have to check out NLTK

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of times your target word occurs in the corpus

```
corpus = ('A B C A B C', 'A D')
target = {'A':0, 'D':0}
# also works for a file
# for line in open('file.txt'):
for line in corpus:
    for word in line.split():
        if word in target:
            target[word] += 1
for (word, count) in target.iteritems():
    print 'word "' + word + '" occurs ' + str(count) + ' times'
```

Begets

```
word "A" occurs 3 times
word "D" occurs 1 times
```